# Keycloak not adding allowed origins to "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header when testing locally, how can I fix it?

Tags: cors, keycloak

I'm getting the following error in the chrome console while redirecting after a successful login:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/realms/careium/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8080' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

My settings currently look like this:

[image: keycloak settings screenshot]

The issues window in chrome looks like this:

[image]

I've been googling and researching this all day and all I can find is other people with similar problems.
Is there a definitive solution for this?

Comment: https://github.com/jangaraj/keycloak-cors-issue-debugging

Comment: @JanGaraj This looks really interesting! Thanks, there's loads to work with there

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that if you've disabled the *"Full scope allowed"* for your KC client [image: Full scope allowed - off]

and you're loading a user profile on KC init, you need to add the `view-profile` scope back to your client. To do so (for KC v21+) go to: *Clients* -> *[your client]* -> *Client scopes* tab -> *[your client]-dedicated* scope -> *Scope* tab -> *Assign roles* button -> select *"Filter by clients"* in the drop down menu -> select *"(account) view profile"*.

The other solution that also worked for me was to disable loading of the user profile on KC init: `loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false`

Answer (score -3):

add * in Web origins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziZgR.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).